# How do I update a Microsoft Access Database with an empty string?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am trying to update my Microsoft Access database with some data from my WPF/C# form. Data from the database is first used to populate the form. Once a user requests to make changes to this form I save the data in a dictionary (i.e. 'OriginalName' and its value), they then make changes and click done, where I save the new data (i.e. NewName and its Value). The problem is that if a part of the database is empty to begin with, and I try to update the database with that empty value, it fails. For example, if the database contains a Name, Gender and Address (Michael, Male, 275 Blue Avenue). The user then changes the Name (James, Male, 275 Blue Avenue), my update runs successfully

```
UPDATE TABLENAME 
SET NameCol = @newName, GenderCol = @newGender, AddressCol = @newAddress 
where NameCol = @OriginalName AND GenderCol = @OriginalGender AND AddressCol = @OriginalAddress
```

All of theses paramters have been set and used in the correct order as followed:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newName",myDictionary["NewName"]);
```

However, if one column is empty it fails. For example, if the Address column is originally empty, the user changes the Name but leaves the Gender and Address the same, the update fails. Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If *the user changes the Name but leaves the Gender and Address the same* what are the values of `@newGender`, `@newAddress`, `@OriginalGender` and `@OriginalAddress`?

Comment: Yes they will be the same value, because after they make changes and click 'done', I take all the values from the form UI again and save these as 'new' values, so if they have not changed the Gender and Address, they are the same values as the original. I checked this in the Dictionary to be sure.

Comment: <sequel>, <mysql> or <ms-access> - too many conflicting tags there. Remove the one(s) not involved.

Comment: When you say that a column has an *empty value*, do you mean an empty string: `''` or NULL? And if the user leaves the empty value for Gender as it is, do you pass `''` or NULL for `@newGender`?

Comment: I advise not to save empty string into fields. I prefer Null.

Comment: @forpas I have just checked and the value comes out the MS-Access database as {} which it says is a static member. Once I assign this to my textbox, I do myTextBox = value.ToString(), therefore converting {} to a string, which appears as Empty (""). When the user leaves the empty value I pass "" back to the database, but I have also tried NULL

Comment: @forpas Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have found a solution where I send a null character back ("\0") if the element is empty. This runs successfully and updates all tables. Thanks again.

Comment: @ba126 . . . Empty strings should represent a value where the value is known and the value has not characters in the string.  Missing or unknown values should be represented using `NULL`.  Although not required, that is pretty much why `NULL` was invented.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, there are two camps in this area. Alllow nulls, or always use a ZLS (zero length string).

I perfer and recommend that all empty strings are nulls. That's just my habit, but I think its better. And the reason of course is that your code WILL encounter lots of nulls EVEN if you NEVER save them. The first time you write a relational join, and often a left join to boot? Well, when no child records exist, then the child table columns WILL  be null and ARE null. As a result, you as a developer will have to code around nulls in the database all the time anyway. Since you HAVE to deal with all those nulls, then might as well adopt the standard that all empty strings are saved as nulls. I in general don't do this for numbers, but for dates, and for strings (text), I adopt the standard that nulls are saved - not the ZLS.

But you can modify the access table - set allow ZLS = true. But now you have a hodge podge of ZLS strings and null strings in a given column.

SELECT * FROM myTable Where City is null

Then becomes

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE City is null or City = ""

It's a real pain.

I suggest this:

```
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "UPDATE tblHotels Set FirstName = @FirstName," &
             "LastName = @LastName," &
             "HotelName = @HotelName," &
             "City = @City " &
             "WHERE ID = @ID"
    Debug.Print(strSQL)
    Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL,
            New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TESTOLEDB))
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = STNull(txtFirstName.Text)
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = STNull(txtLastName.Text)
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@HotelName", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = STNull(txtHotelName.Text)
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = STNull(txtCity.Text)
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtID.Text

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmdSQL.Dispose()

    End Using

End Sub

Public Function STNull(s As String) As Object
    If s = "" Then
        Return DBNull.Value
    Else
        Return s
    End If
End Function

Public Function NullST(s As Object) As Object

    If IsDBNull(s) Then
        Return ""
    Else
        Return s
    End If
End Function
```

So I built a routine to get/convert nulls to "" and back again.

Thus, to load control values, you have this:

```
    Dim rst As New DataTable
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * from tblHotels WHERE ID = " & txtID.Text
    Using cmdSQL As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQL,
        New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TESTOLEDB))
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        cmdSQL.Dispose()
    End Using

    If rst.Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    With rst.Rows(0)
        txtFirstName.Text = NullST(.Item("FirstName"))
        txtLastName.Text = NullST(.Item("LastName"))
        txtHotelName.Text = NullST(.Item("HotelName"))
        txtCity.Text = NullST(.Item("City"))
    End With
```